# Ceiling drywall - options for dealing with joists slightly higher than beam?

Tags: drywall

I'm planning to drywall a garage in my house.  The garage has floor joists above that are 12" OC.  The joists connect to beams but are not even with the bottom of the beam (the offset varies between about 1/4" to 1/2") - see picture.

This will be my first time doing drywall.  What's the best way to get an even ceiling?  should I put furring strips perpendicular to the joists?  Along the joists?

Alternatively, what are other (maybe easier) options for dealing with the beams?  Wrap them in drywall?  Leave them exposed somehow?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

[image: Garage ceiling joists and beams]

Comment: hpw much clearance is there above that  door?

Comment: That's a different issue that I have to deal with, but I'll be getting new doors and there will be room enough.

Comment: You need more pictures.   Also I don't understand why a garage gets drywall on a ceiling with nothing above it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to pack down each joist as you say with a furring strip.

It's slightly complicated if you say the gap varies, especially if it's from one end of the joist to the other, i.e. tapers. Then it's tight string line time between the beams and measure each furring strip and cut each to size.

But since it's a garage, you might get away with a 1/2" strip everywhere if a slightly lower standard of absolute flatness is acceptable.

Comment: Using a laser level can help set those furring strips.